# PHP - Input a string from a URL?

Tags: php

Is it possible to input the string from the url in the code.

"http://website.com?ip=123.com"

```
 $statut = file_get_contents('http://www.example.com/index.php?Etat_Query&ip=',$ip,'&port=25565');
```

i want `$ip` to be replaced with the variable `123.com` from the URL.

(Sorry my english is not the best)

Comment: Are you just looking for `$_GET['ip']`?

Comment: `,` should be `.` to connect two strings. Otherwise the simple answer to your question is `yes it's possible`

Answer (score 1):

Of course it is possible but you have to [URL Encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) your `ip` variable in the URL using this :

```
$encoded = urlencode('123.com');
```

For your specific example it's not necessary but if the URL is more complicated (like using '&'...) it will be necessary.

Then your `$ip` variable would just be :

```
$ip = $_GET['ip'];
```

Let me just warn you about a security issue that could occur using this method, like malicious php script that could be downloaded to your server.